# twitchio How can I make Twitch Bot commands available to managers only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitch, twitch-api

How can I make Twitch Bot commands available to managers only?
Some commands are only available to the manager, and some commands are available to everyone.

that is my code:

```
from twitchio.ext import commands
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from decouple import config

temp_initial_channels = str(config('CHANNEL'))
temp_xlsx_name = str(config('XLSX_NAME'))

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(irc_token=config('TMI_TOKEN'), client_id=config('CLIENT_ID'), nick=config('BOT_NICK'), prefix=config('BOT_PREFIX'),
                         initial_channels=[temp_initial_channels])

    async def event_ready(self):
        ws = bot._ws
        await ws.send_privmsg("whitebot201", f"whitebot201 이 준비 완료 되었습니다!")

    async def event_message(self, message):
        print(message.content)
        await self.handle_commands(message)
    
    @commands.command(name='test')
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'test pass!!!')


bot = Bot()
bot.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand your code to support reading IRCv3 tags.

You'll need to enable the tags capability

Send

> CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags

Before joining any rooms

Then read the `badges` of the tags of a `PRIVMSG` and look for the `broadcaster` or `moderator` badge existing in the `badges` key of the IRCv3 Tags

For example:

> @badge-info=;badges=moderator/1,ambassador/1;client-nonce=ba9231972a6341b6370876a2eb159723;color=#033700;display-name=BarryCarlyon;emotes=;flags=;id=a69c4d4d-541f-4615-89e9-ba278580a2eb;mod=1;room-id=56410307;subscriber=0;tmi-sent-ts=1614265271314;turbo=0;user-id=15185913;user-type=mod :barrycarlyon!barrycarlyon@barrycarlyon.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #somechannel :test

You can see I have the `moderator` and `ambassador` badges.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved this problem with this:

Comment: ctx.author.is_mod / message.author.is_mod